# Find Out Dynamic IP address of Computer using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've to check that system has  static or dynamic IP Address & then display ITs Dynamic address.I know how to find out static address.I want to know how to find out Dynamic IP address.....

Comment: You mean the dynamic ip address of the web site/web server ? You have your site behind an adsl router that change the ip - correct ? and search that ip and how you see you outside ? - Or you mean the ip of your viewers ?

Comment: I want to find out IP of viewers

Answer (score 1):

The ip of the viewers are get from

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

or

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx

If the user is behind a proxy you may also need to check some more server variables as I describe them on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514717/159270